# Automatically add additional source directories to eclipse build path for maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3

I have a maven project conforming to the standard maven directory structure that has lots of unit and integration tests lying on top of each other in the src/test/java directory. I would like

- An additional source directory (src/integration-test/java)
- Eclipse to automatically realise there is this extra directory if possible
- Unit tests run by surefire, integration tests run by failsafe

I have tried using the build-helper-maven-plugin every way I can think of yet eclipse still doesn't seem to see the new directory on the build path.

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: First off, are you using M2E and is it recognized as a Maven project?

Comment: Better follow the naming convention for unit and integration tests (unit tests see [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) for integration tests see [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) than you don't need build-helper-maven-plugins. You can simply put the in `src/test/java`

Comment: @khmarbaise I wanted to avoid having all the tests in the src/test/java directory if I could. That way it would be easier to run just the unit or integration tests from eclipse.

Comment: @nitind yes to both.

Comment: May be it would be better to make a separate integration test module where you can locate your integegration tests into `src/test/java` as well...

Comment: I guess what I'm really after is a convenient way to run just my unit tests or just my integration tests in Eclipse. In the past I've run a subset of my tests by right clicking the folder and then "Run As JUnit Test" and assumed this was the way to go. If there is an Eclipse alternative which keeps all the tests together I'm happy to go with that instead.